# reakit - infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

```
import { useTabState, Tab, TabList, TabPanel } from "reakit/Tab";

function App() {
  alert("oi")
  const tab = useTabState();
  return (
    <>
      <TabList {...tab} aria-label="My tabs">
        <Tab {...tab}>Tab 1</Tab>
        <Tab {...tab}>Tab 2</Tab>
      </TabList>
      <TabPanel {...tab}>Tab 1</TabPanel>
      <TabPanel {...tab}>Tab 2</TabPanel>
    </>
  );
}
```

Then I render this functional component with:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

The code above creates tabs. When I click on the tabs, the browser spawns alert modals infinitely. Why?

Comment: You might not put `alert("oi")` into the render method / function body of an component. Does this help?

Comment: @Colin Why not? More specifically, why is it triggering an infinite chain of alerts for me?

Comment: Have you omitted some code? I can't see an issue in what you've provided

Comment: @Dominic I don’t know if I omitted relevant code. To reproduce: ```npx create-react-app my-app```, modify the App.js with the one I posted, and then ```npm start```.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It shows the alert 8 times.

Comment: @Colin That in itself is weird. Why 8 times?

Comment: I have seen a similar issue asked on Stackoverflow earlier. So, by nature, alert is shown `2 times` in a `single` render. I tried to reproduce this and tried to do it `without reakit` and what I find is `without reakit`, it `renders once` and `alert` is showing `twice`. And `with reakit`,  it is shown `8times` due to `4 re-renders`.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh When I first load the page, I get 6 alerts. Then I click on "Tab 2" and it shows infinite alerts.

Comment: Hey, don't know `reakit` internally, but it is making react to render `twice` in one go, due to which it is rendering `6 times`. And yes switching to tab 2 is leading to an infinite alerts.